# Choosing the right motors for an electric wheelchair

Tags: torque

I'm currently building an electric wheelchair. It will have to carry a maximum weight of 600 lbs. I'd like it to have a max speed of about 1.5 mph. The tires I'm using have a 9 inch outer diameter. How much torque would I need to do this?

Comment: This is a mechanical engineering question.

Comment: Can not be answered with those specifications.

Comment: What else do you need?

Comment: Rotational inertial mass of your wheelchair and estimate on internal frictions. Or just overspend onmotor size.

Comment: mass is approximately 55kg. It will be used on paved ground (asphalt) and grass primarily.

Comment: Add your info in comments to the question.

Comment: Perhaps you should check out “rotational inertia”…

Comment: You need to work out the maximum acceleration required and on what gradient. Get a luggage weight gauge, attach it to the wheelchair and pull starting from rest at an acceptable acceleration rate. Use metric system, take the max weight in kg and convert to newtons (units of force) by multiplying by 9.8 m/s/s (acceleration due to gravity). That's step 1.

Comment: Yeah so generally you will not get an answer to this question. Though the luggage scale answer is good. The immediate problem is that all people who ask this question assume that weight is the primary concern of the question. But it is not, the primary concern is acceleration of a rotating mass and losses in the system. So at minimum we need an estimate to the I term in formula $$T=I\alpha$$ While mass comes into play we are generally more interested in how the mass is distributed in the system rather than total mass. But since the losses are impossible to calculate dragging with a scale is

Comment: a good suggestion since it captures both I and losses in system in one go. Or again overspend on the motor then adjust it to not be so fast. This question gets asked a lot but because its a bit more involved than assumed almost never gets resolved...